# Django permissions: Access to only one view method among many

Tags: python, django, django-permissions

Hi I have a project with many methods in view. Each method mapped to different urls.

*views.py*

```
def method1(request):
    print 'hello world'

def method2(request):
    print 'hello world2'

def method3(request):
    print 'hello world3'
```

What i want is to do something related to permission so that the user can access only one method.
e.g
That is if user has permission for method2(), he/she can only access this method. He/she mustn't access method1() or method2().

Like described here https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1703/, I can use user_pass_test() function but in this way i can restrict only one.

If I want to restrict all except one i have to apply decorators in all existing methods and there are alot of methods in my project.

Here I want to restrict all except one.

Please help.

Comment: By decoders do you mean decorators?

Comment: Yes, sorry it was a mistake. Has corrected.

Comment: You should try django-guardian, it's a pretty good app to manage permissions with decorators :D

Answer (score 1):

Django's permissions might or not be the right way to tell if a given user can access a given view, but you don't tell enough about the context.

But Anyway... There are mainly two solutions here: either decorate each and every view with the appropriate `user_passes_test(yourtesthere)` or `permission_required(perm)` decorator, or [use a custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#process_view) with the `process_view` method.

Comment: I was not able to use custom middleware. Can you help me with some example.